# Are there browser or tag jump such as LSP for `inherit` of Bitbake recipes?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, yocto, bitbake, recipe

I can't understand deep `inherit` of Bitbake recipes such as following:

https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/imx-manifest

On the other hand, I'm using tag jump GNU global (tag jump) to read C code,
and LSP and vscode to read C++ and the other languages.

Are there browser or tag jump such as LSP to understand `inherit` of Bitbake recipes?

Best regards, Kiwamu Okabe

Comment: Someone uses this? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EugenWiens.bitbake

Comment: It must be a way in vscode to detect `inherit` keyword and look for the corresponding `class.bbclass` and interpret all your code to test the matching, but I never saw something like that yet